# Creating virtual pages dynamically using jQuery Mobile

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I try to link virtual pages using jQuery Mobile, but I have two problems :

- The first time when I load the page, the CSS is not applied.
- After when I choose a page and I want to change to another page, I notice that every time I passed by the page 1.

This is my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cFens/4/).

Code :

```
            var nbrButton = 3;
            $(document).ready(function(){
                for(i = 1;i <= nbrButton;i++) {

                    $("body").append('<div id="p'+i+'" data-role="page" class="pages"><div data-role="content">Page'+i+'</br><a data-role="button" rel="internal" href="#p1"  data-inline="true">1</a><a data-role="button" rel="internal" href="#p2"  data-inline="true">2</a><a data-role="button" rel="internal" href="#p3"  data-inline="true">3</a></div></div>');

                }
                $("#p1").show();

            });
```

Could you tell me what is the problem or if there is a better way to do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

I also removed `data-rel="internal"` in the links.

**Answer**

I have done the below.

instead of

```
$('#p1').show();
```

I add this

```
$.mobile.changePage( '#p1', { allowSamePageTransition: true });
```

It will refresh Page-1 `p1` to reload styles.

Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/AS6s7/).

Comment: Great ! it remains the second problem. Thank you.

Comment: Page 1 won't appear when moving to other pages. is this your second problem?

Comment: yes ! I forgot to remove **$('#p1').show()** 

_شكراً جزيلا عمر_

Comment: Remove `data-rel="internal"` Afwan akhi :) _(you're welcome in Arabic)_

Comment: I understand, I speak arabic :)

Comment: Great :) I'm glad I've been of help.

Comment: Sorry, How can I make the button selected(the color is changed) for every page selected, something like that : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/845069example.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26656/discussion-between-omar-and-mils)

Answer (score 2):

You can't dynamically create new jQuery Mobile page (you can, but that page will not have styles) unless you have at least one existing. There's a workaround here, you can create an empty jQuery mobile page and use it to create a new one.

Here's a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
    <script>
                $(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){       
                    $('<div>').attr({'data-role':'page','id':'second'}).appendTo('body');
                    $('<div>').attr({'data-role':'header','id':'second-header'}).append('<h3>Header Title</h3>').appendTo('#second');
                    $.mobile.changePage("#second");
                });    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">

    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Now you should use a pageshow page event of a first hidden page to create new dynamic pages. After page are cretaed just use change page to show a first visible page.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know in advance the number of pages..
Thank you.

Comment: Why is this a problem in case of my example? Just copy your code inside pageshow example.

Answer (score -1):

To apply CSS styles just add `$("#p1").trigger('create');` as last line after  `$("#p1").show();`